# Can I have one piece of a flash drive dedicated to just files whereas the other piece is a bootable file system?

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning

I'm putting my 16 GB flashdrive to the max. This is how I currently have it set up:

```
+---------------------------------------+
|  Partition  |  File System  |  Mount  |
+---------------------------------------+
| Partition 1 |     EXT4      |    /    |
| Partition 2 |     EXT4      |  /home  |
| Partition 3 |     FAT32     |         |
+---------------------------------------+
```

When I plug it into a Ubuntu virtual machine, I see all three partitions perfectly.
However, when I plug it into my Windows box, I am asked to format the disk before I can use it.

Why is this? I have set up a FAT partition, which Windows should detect and be able to work with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Partitioning a bootable Flash drive](http://superuser.com/questions/22308/partitioning-a-bootable-flash-drive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, Windows expects to be able to read the first partition on a flash drive. Because the Disk Management tool in newer versions of Windows doesn't even allow partitioning of flash drives, I'm not sure if Windows will even detect the extra partitions at all.

Try making the FAT32 volume the first partition on the flash drive (so that Windows will read it) and setting one of the other partitions as bootable. You should be able to boot from a partition other than the first one.

In other words, your partitioning should look like this, with Partition 2 set as bootable:

```
+---------------------------------------+
|  Partition  |  File System  |  Mount  |
+---------------------------------------+
| Partition 1 |     FAT32     |         |
| Partition 2 |     EXT4      |    /    |
| Partition 3 |     EXT4      |  /home  |
+---------------------------------------+
```